# Converting Optim to constrOptim in R

Tags: r

I am trying to determine the weights of 9 metrics which will return the highest accuracy ratio. Since they are weights, the values need to sum to 1 and lie between 0 & 1. I am currently using the optim function, but do to constraints, I think I need to switch to constrOptim. I was wondering the best way to do this. Below I have included the code i am currently using. x.matrix is 20,000 by 9 matrix of values ranked between 1-10.

```
pars<-c(w1=(1/9),w2=(1/9),w3=(1/9),w4=(1/9),w5=(1/9),w6=(1/9),w7=(1/9),w8=(1/9),w9=(1/9))

OptPars<-function(pars){(-(rcorr.cens(x.matrix%*%pars),f)["Dxy"])}

opt<-optim(pars,OptPars)
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you have values `x` on the range `(-Inf, Inf)` and you need values `p` in the range `[0,1]` that sum to 1, you can do the following transformation

```
p <- exp(x)/sum(exp(x))
```

If you do that translation in your optimization function and do the same transformation on the best set of parameters, you should get what you want.

Comment: Sorry if this is a simple question but I'm new to R. So is the following what you are suggesting.    OptPars<-function(pars){par<-exp(pars)/sum(exp(pars))(-(rcorr.cens(x.matrix%*%par),f)["Dxy"]))}

Comment: @user3666589 Indeed. And then when you get the final `opt` object, also do `exp(opt$par)/sum(exp(opt$par))`

Comment: when I run this it gives a value for each variable when I know that a 0 weighting would improve the accuracy, is there a way of remedying this or not through the optim function

Comment: @user3666589 If you want to fix a weight, don't include it as an optimization parameter. If the weights have to sum to 1, they can't call be zero.

Comment: sorry if last post was somewhat vague, when I run the function/code it returns values for each of the metrics, but from manual manipulation I know that if certain variables were given a weight of 0 it would improve the accuracy, will this function give a variable a 0 weighting if it determines it beneficial/improve accuracy or will it automatically give it some weighting. Also thanks for all of your input so far, its saving endless hours browsing and haphazard searching.

Comment: @user3666589 It's unlikely that any of those transformed values will be exactly 0, just as it's unlikely to be exactly .5. They can get very, very small. You may want to try some iterative optimization. If any of the final `par` values are very small, remove them, and then optimize again.

Comment: so once i run trial<-optim(pars,OptPars) i get: w1=0.1087882, w2=0.1155187, w3=0.1008479, w4=0.1103080, w5=0.1194883, w6=0.1120128, w7=0.1104364, w8=0.1107336, w9=0.1205574. I then re-weight: trial.weights<-exp(trial$par)/sum(exp(trial$par)) and get: w1=0.1107446 , w2=0.1114925, w3=0.1098687, w4=0.1109130, w5=0.1119359, w6=0.1111023,w7=0.1109272, w8=0.1109602, and w9=0.1120556. If this is correct approach would it be best to create a loop to find the best metrics. Also why is the exponential used rather than simply pars/sum(pars)?

Comment: @user3666589 Optim will try values from `-Inf` to `Inf`. The `exp()` keeps everything positive. It's important to use a method you understand. If you don't like this one, feel free to look for others.

Comment: I was just trying to gain a better understanding of the approach, thanks for all the input