# EM-Algorithm with parameter restrictions using R

Tags: r, statistics, expectation-maximization

Using any type of data, in my case data from three gamma distributions mixed, the goal is to parameterise the distributions' theta and the distribution weight alpha that are all 0< and sum to 1.

How do I restrict the alphas to sum to one, where no alpha is negative?

```
func1<-function(x, comp_numb=3, a=c(0,0,0), k=c(0,0,0), th=c(0,0,0), maxit=10, tol=0.3){

  a1<-c(1/3,1/3,1/3)
  k1<-c(0.1,0.1,0.1)
  th1<-c(0.1,0.1,0.1)
  m<-2
  sumcomp<-numeric(comp_numb)
  out<-matrix(,length(x),comp_numb)
  
  the<-matrix(,maxit, comp_numb)
  alp<-matrix(,maxit, comp_numb)
  
  if(a==0 && k==0 && th==0){ # controlling initial parameter values
    a<-a1                
    k<-k1  
    th<-th1
  }
  
  while(m<=maxit+1){    # iteration
    for (l in 1:length(x)){
      for (i in 1:comp_numb){ # estimating the denominator sum in fY|X=x
        
    sumcomp[i]<-(a[i]*x[l]^(k[i]-1)*exp(-x[l]/th[i]))/(gamma(k[i])*(th[i])^k[i])
    
    # estimating the numerator in fY|X=x
    out[l,i]<-(a[i]*((x[l]^(k[i]-1)*exp(-x[i]/th[i]))/(gamma(k[i])*(th[i])^k[i]))/sum(sumcomp))
    
  } #close out loop
}   #close x loop  

for (i in 1:comp_numb){ # estimating parameters
  
  a[i]<- sum(out[,i])/length(x) #replacing alphas
  
  th[i]<- sum(x*out[,i])/(k[i]*sum(out[,i])) # replacing thetas
  
  alp[m-1,i]<-a[i] # stacking parameters
  the[m-1,i]<-th[i]
  
  if(m>3){
    difalp<-abs(alp[m-1,]-alp[m-2,]) ##change in alpha estimate
    difthe<-abs(the[m-1,]-the[m-2,]) ##change in theta estimate
  }
  
} # close parameter estimator

if(m>3){
  if(all(difalp<tol) && all(difthe<tol))break} ##breaks while loop if dif<tol

m<-m+1
  } # close while loop parameter maximator
  print(alp)
  print(the)
} # close function
```

Comment: Here's a relevant transformation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835294/converting-optim-to-constroptim-in-r.

Comment: The mixture weights are computed from the "responsibility" p(component | datum), so by construction they are nonnegative and sum to 1. If you are seeing something else, there is a bug in your code; in that case maybe you should post the output you are seeing.

Comment: Hi Robert, Thank you for your input. The output I get from printing the alpha parameter is three vectors, one for each distribution, about the size:

 [,1] 1.866397e+170
 [,2] 1.866397e+170     
 [,3] 4.046550e-02

Comment: As you see they are not bound to any restrictions, how do I impose that?